# my brake pedal is sticking in the depressed position in cold weather

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, truck

I have a 95 Chevrolet K1500 pickup and I have recently had the brake booster replaced and it worked fine for the past year but now my pedal is sticking in the pressed position but only in colder weather.

Is this a booster problem or maybe the master cylinder?

Answer (score 1):

If the brakes are firmly on while the pedal is stuck down, then the fault will be in the booster.  One of the vacuum valves in the booster may be sticking in the cold, or an leak may form in the rear of booster.

If the brakes are not on, then it could be the master cylinder if you are not loosing fluid.

Answer (score 0):

you can try lubing the brake pedal joint as a quick tip and if not follow HandyHowie's solution.